# Remove string from filename for all files (image files) available in the directory without affecting its extensions

Tags: php, image, rename, str-replace, file-rename

Need to remove user requested string from file name. This below is my function.

```
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/files/';
$strString = $objArray['frmName']; // Name to remove which comes from an array.

function doActionOnRemoveStringFromFileName($strString, $directory) {
    if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if(!strstr($file,$strString)) {
                    continue; 
                }
                $newfilename = str_replace($strString,"",$file);
                rename($directory . $file,$directory . $newfilename);
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }   
}
```

It works partially good. But the mistake what in this routine is, renaming action also takes on file's extensions. What i need is, Only to rename the file and it should not to be affect its file extensions. Any suggestions please. Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have libraries written by myself that have some of those functions. Look:

```
//Returns the filename but ignores its extension
function getFileNameWithOutExtension($filename) {
     $exploded = explode(".", $filename);
     array_pop($exploded);

     //Included a DOT as parameter in implode so, in case the
     //filename contains DOT
     return implode(".", $exploded);
}

//Returns the extension
function getFileExtension($file) {
    $exploded = explode(".", $file);
    $ext = end($exploded);
    return $ext;
}
```

So you use

```
$replacedname = str_replace($strString,"", getFileNameWithOutExtension($file));

$newfilename = $replacedname.".".getFileExtension($file);
```

Check it working here:
http://codepad.org/CAKdCAA0

Comment: It works fine brother, but there is an issue in this routine. Means it only performs action on file when the file name shouldn't have any dots except extension's. otherwise it returns wrong result. How to get rid on it if the filename contains more than one dot??

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply. This codepad link got expired. Any how I'll accept this as an answer. Thanks brother. :)